# Select all check box inside a group only in group type multi select dropdown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

When i select all option only those options are checked in those are come under one group.
Like if i select Select All then only Apple,Pear,Orange got selected.

```
<select title="Fruits" multiple="multiple" id="fruits" name="fruits[]">
        <opt-group label="ABC" class="fruit">
                <option label="All" value=""> Select All</option>
                <option label="apple" value="1">Apple</option>
                <option label="pear" value="2">Pear</option>
                <option label="orange" value="3">Orange</option>
      </opt-group>
            <opt-group label="Cd" class="berries">
                <option label="All" value="">Select All</option>
                <option label="strawberry" value="4">Strawberry</option>
                <option label="raspberry" value="5">Raspberry</option>
                <option label="blueberry" value="6">Blueberry</option>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to do? Do you want to select the "selected" options? or you want to return all options inside of 'opt-group'?

Comment: I want to return all options inside of opt-group.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return all items inside of an `opt-group`, you just need to use a selector like this:

```
 $("opt-group option")
```

OR

```
 $("opt-group").children().find("option")
```

It will return all `option` within `opt-group` tag regardless of being selected or not. The second one is suitable when you have nested `option` tags inside of `opt-group` tag.